# Do parentheses in a SQL Server View impact performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

When I added a set of parentheses around an "OR" statement in MS SQL Server View query, the performance suffered dramatically.

I ran across a view that had a join with a complicated set of `and` / `or` clauses in it. I thought the statement would be easier to read and maintain with the addition of parentheses. After I added the parentheses, though, the view performance tanked.

- I ran this statement: `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [ViewName]`. Result was
  630,644. Query took 14 seconds to process.
- Then added a set of parentheses to the view definition and ran the
  same `COUNT(*)` statement. Stopped the query after 75 seconds; it had
  still not completed.
- Removed the parentheses from the view. `COUNT(*)` again. Result took
  15 seconds.
- Added parentheses again. `COUNT(*)` query took 90 seconds before I
  stopped it.

This leads me to believe that the parentheses were definitely impacting the performance of the view. But everything I have read says that parentheses in SQL don't impact performance.

What am I missing?

Comment: how many times have you done that scenario?

Comment: You said the parentheses were around an OR statement..were there any other conditions within the WHERE clause? If so, then the WHERE Condition potentially changes drastically with the OR condition in play. OR Conditions can drive a RBAR parse as I recall.

Comment: Sounds like your `WHERE` clause filtering changed, logically, when you added the parens.  If you could post your view definition, that would help us troubleshoot.

Comment: A set of parentheses _where_? If you want specific help about what parentheses might have changed about your query logic or the plan that was produced, please add specific information to the question. [Start with this topic in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You might want to read about [Logical Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/logical-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Share the view definition with and without parenthesis.

Comment: Based on the level of detail in this question, I'm going to assume your parenthesis changed the logic of the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> This leads me to believe that the parentheses were definitely impacting the performance of the view. But everything I have read says that parentheses in SQL don't impact performance.

It depends where parentheses been applied. sometimes it applies with no effect on logic, and sometime there is effect i.e. as per following example, in Example 1 there would be effect on query processing eventually on performance, but in Example 2 there won't be any effect with adding parentheses

**Example 1**

```
ColumnA = 0 and ColmnB = 1 or ColumnB = 2
ColumnA = 0 and (ColmnB = 1 or ColumnB = 2)
ColumnA = 0 and ColmnB = 1 or (ColumnB = 2)
```

**Example 2**

```
ColumnA = 0 and ColmnB = 1 
ColumnA = 0 and (ColmnB = 1)
(ColumnA = 0) and ColmnB = 1
```

> with a complicated set of and / or clauses in it

Further more, I would suggest look at execution plan as well for clear understanding, this you can enable in SSMS (shortcut `ctrl+m`) before executing the query, and see the difference in each execution:

- How many tasks query had to perform to get the result
- What type of tasks query had to perform
- What are the `estimated rows` and `Actual number of rows` in each task
- Index usage changed, any new indexes required etc...